# Does OPcache work when PHP is running in CGI mode?

Tags: php5, cache, cgi

Does PHP 5.5s OPcache work with PHP running in CGI mode?

Or does that even make sense, since it forks and kills PHP for each request?

Comment: No idea, but using CGI mode certainly doesn't make any sense.